# stratified sampling in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy I have a dataset like this. The first two columns are indices. I can divide my dataset into blocks via the indices, i.e. first block is 0 0 second block is 0 1 third block 0 2 then 1 0, 1 1, 1 2 and so on and so forth. Each block has at least two elements. The numbers in the indices columns can vary

I need to split the dataset along these blocks 80%-20% randomly such that after the split each block in both datasets has at least 1 element. How could I do that?

```
indices | real data
        |
0   0   | 43.25 665.32 ...  } 1st block
0   0   | 11.234            }
0   1     ...               } 2nd block
0   1                       } 
0   2                       } 3rd block
0   2                       }
1   0                       } 4th block
1   0                       }
1   0                       }
1   1                       ...
1   1                       
1   2
1   2
2   0
2   0 
2   1
2   1
2   1
...
```

Comment: Could you post some runnable python code that represents the data you are describing?

Comment: I'm misunderstanding how you want to split... How I understand it is that after the split you have dataset `A` and dataset `B`.  If every block must be represented in both `A` and `B`, and if each block has as few as 2 elements, how can you split it 80/20 and have 1 element in each split.  Isn't that 50/50 for each of the blocks with two elements?  In your example data, they have at most three, so the largest ratio you could get is 66/33.  Is your sample data not representative?

Comment: @askewchan you are correct, in the real dataset there are a lot more elements in each block so it is possible to split approximately 20-80%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See how do you like this. To introduce randomness, I am shuffling the entire dataset. It is the only way I have figured how to do the splitting vectorized. Maybe you could simply shuffle an indexing array, but that was one indirection too many for my brain today. I have also used a structured array, for ease in extracting the blocks. First, lets create a sample dataset:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

# Create a sample data set
c1, c2 = 10, 5
idx1, idx2 = np.arange(c1), np.arange(c2)
idx1, idx2 = np.repeat(idx1, c2), np.tile(idx2, c1)

items = 1000
i = np.random.randint(c1*c2, size=(items - 2*c1*c2,))
d = np.random.rand(items+5)

dataset = np.empty((items+5,), [('idx1', np.int), ('idx2', np.int),
                             ('data', np.float)])
dataset['idx1'][:2*c1*c2] =  np.tile(idx1, 2)
dataset['idx1'][2*c1*c2:-5] = idx1[i]
dataset['idx2'][:2*c1*c2] = np.tile(idx2, 2)
dataset['idx2'][2*c1*c2:-5] = idx2[i]
dataset['data'] = d
# Add blocks with only 2 and only 3 elements to test corner case
dataset['idx1'][-5:] = -1
dataset['idx2'][-5:] = [0] * 2 + [1]*3
```

And now the stratified sampling:

```
# For randomness, shuffle the entire array
np.random.shuffle(dataset)

blocks, _ = np.unique(dataset[['idx1', 'idx2']], return_inverse=True)
block_count = np.bincount(_)
where = np.argsort(_)
block_start = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(block_count)[:-1]))

# If we have n elements in a block, and we assign 1 to each array, we
# are left with only n-2. If we randomly assign a fraction x of these
# to the first array, the expected ratio of items will be
# (x*(n-2) + 1) : ((1-x)*(n-2) + 1)
# Setting the ratio equal to 4 (80/20) and solving for x, we get
# x = 4/5 + 3/5/(n-2)

x = 4/5 + 3/5/(block_count - 2)
x = np.clip(x, 0, 1) # if n in (2, 3), the ratio is larger than 1
threshold = np.repeat(x, block_count)
threshold[block_start] = 1 # first item goes to A
threshold[block_start + 1] = 0 # seconf item goes to B

a_idx = threshold > np.random.rand(len(dataset))

A = dataset[where[a_idx]]
B = dataset[where[~a_idx]]
```

After running it, the split is roughly 80/20, and all blocks are represented in both arrays:

```
>>> len(A)
815
>>> len(B)
190
>>> np.all(np.unique(A[['idx1', 'idx2']]) == np.unique(B[['idx1', 'idx2']]))
True
```

Comment: Maybe this is a different question but if I already have a matrix with many columns, how can I give titles 'idx1' and 'idx2' to the first 2 columns and 'data' to the rest?

Comment: works perfect, only modification I had to make is `x = 4./5. + 3./5./(block_count - 2)` Thanks a lot for the thorough answer!

Comment: @siamii In python 2, if you include the `from __future__ import division`, then `4/5` returns the float `0.8` instead of the usual int `0`.  This is standard behavior in python 3, hence the 'future'.

Comment: Now the problem is that sometimes `a_idx = threshold > np.random.rand(len(dataset))` can produce really skewed ratio within certain blocks, i.e 5%-95% or 45%-55%. It would be better if all ratios within all blocks were as close as possible to 20%-80%

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution. I'm open for a code review if it is possible to implement this in a more numpy way (without for loops). @Jamie 's answer is really good, it's just that sometimes it produces skewed ratios within blocks of data.

```
    ratio = 0.8
    IDX1 = 0
    IDX2 = 1
    idx1s = np.arange(len(np.unique(self.data[:,IDX1])))
    idx2s = np.arange(len(np.unique(self.data[:,IDX2])))
    valid = None
    train = None
    for i1 in idx1s:
        for i2 in idx2:
            mask = np.nonzero((data[:,IDX1] == i1) & (data[:,IDX2] == i2))
            curr_data = data[mask,:]
            np.random.shuffle(curr_data)
            start = np.min(mask)
            end = np.max(mask)
            thres = start + np.around((end - start) * ratio).astype(np.int)

            selected = mask < thres
            train_idx = mask[0][selected[0]]
            valid_idx = mask[0][~selected[0]]
            if train != None:
                train = np.vstack((train,data[train_idx]))
                valid = np.vstack((valid,data[valid_idx]))
            else:
                train = data[train_idx]
                valid = data[valid_idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that each block has at least two entries and also that if it has more than two you want them assigned as closely as possible to 80/20. The easiest way to do this seems to be to assign a random number to all rows, and then choose based on percentiles within each stratified sample. Say this is the data in file strat_sample.csv:

```
Index_1,Index_2,Data_1,Data_2
0,0,0.614583182,0.677644482
0,0,0.321384981,0.598450854
0,0,0.303029607,0.300593782
0,0,0.646010758,0.612006715
0,0,0.484572883,0.30052535
0,1,0.010625416,0.118671475
0,1,0.428967984,0.23795173
0,1,0.523440618,0.457275922
0,1,0.379612652,0.337640868
0,1,0.338180659,0.206399031
1,0,0.079386,0.890939911
1,0,0.572864624,0.725615079
1,0,0.045891404,0.300128917
1,0,0.578792198,0.100698871
1,0,0.776485138,0.475135948
1,0,0.401850419,0.784835723
1,1,0.087660923,0.497299605
1,1,0.8460978,0.825774802
1,1,0.526015021,0.581905971
1,1,0.23324672,0.299475291
```

Then this code (using Pandas data structures) works as desired

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import pandas as pd
#sample data strat_sample.csv, contents to follow

def TreatmentOneCount(n , *args):
    #assign a minimum one to each group but as close as possible to fraction OptimalRatio in group 1. 
    OptimalRatio = args[0]
    if n < 2:
        print("N too small, assignment not defined.")
        a = NaN
    elif n == 2:
        a = 1
    else:
        """
        There are one of two numbers that are close to the target ratio, one above, the other below
        If the number above is N and it is closest to optimal, then you need to set things to N-1 to ensure both groups have at least one member (recall n>2)
        If the number below is 0 and it is closest to optimal, then you need to set things to 1 to ensure both groups have at least one member (recall n>2)
        """
        targetassigment = OptimalRatio * n
        if  targetassigment - floor(targetassigment) > 0.5:
            a = min(ceil(targetassigment),n-1)
        else:
            a = max(floor(targetassigment),1)
    return a


df = pd.read_csv('strat_sample.csv', sep=','  , header=0)

#assign a random number to each entry
df['RandScore'] =  np.random.uniform(0,1,df.shape[0])
df.sort(columns= ['Index_1' ,'Index_2','RandScore'], inplace = True)

#Within each block assign a rank based on random number. 
df['RandRank'] = df.groupby(['Index_1','Index_2'])['RandScore'].rank()

#make a group index
df['MasterIdx'] = df['Index_1'].apply(str) + df['Index_2'].apply(str)

#Store the counts for members of each block
seriestest = df.groupby('MasterIdx')['RandRank'].count()
seriestest.name = "Counts"
dftest = pd.DataFrame(seriestest)

#Add the block counts to the data
df = df.merge(dftest, how='left',  left_on = 'MasterIdx', right_index= True)

#Make the actual assignments to the two groups
df['Assignment'] = (df['RandRank'] <=  df['Counts'].apply(TreatmentOneCount, args = (0.8,))) * -1 + 2
df.drop(['MasterIdx', 'Counts', 'RandRank', 'RandScore'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
from sklearn import cross_validation

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```