# Python random sampling in multiple indices

Tags: python, sampling

I have a data frame according to below:

```
id_1  id_2  value
1     0     1
1     1     2
1     2     3
2     0     4
2     1     1
3     0     5
3     1     1
4     0     5
4     1     1
4     2     6
4     3     7  
11    0     8
11    1     14
13    0     10
13    1     9
```

I would like to take out a random sample of size n, without replacement, from this table based on *id_1*. This row needs to be unique with respect to the *id_1* column and can only occur once.

End result something like:

```
id_1  id_2  value
1     1     2
2     0     4
4     3     7
13    0     10
```

I have tried to do a group by and use the indices to take out a row through *random.sample* but it dosent go all the way.

Can someone give me a pointer on how to make this work? Code for DF below!

As always, thanks for time and input!

/swepab

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_1' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,11,11,13,13],
               'id_2' : [0,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1],
               'value_col' : [1,2,3,4,1,5,1,5,1,6,7,8,14,10,9]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using vectorized functions (not loops) using

```
import numpy as np

uniqued = df.id_1.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index)).drop_duplicates()

df.ix[np.random.choice(uniqued.index, 1, replace=False)]
```

`uniqued` is created by a random shuffle + choice of a unique element by `id_1`. Then, a random sample (without replacement) is generated on it.

Comment: Ok, this looks neat, and also fast which is good since its a lot of data. Let me test runt it real quick and get back in a few moments!

Comment: @swepab Looking back on this, it's possible to make this faster by performing the first part only on the `id_1` column. See update.

Comment: Just a final question, if you dont mind - is there a way to stratify the sample so it factors in the size of *id_2* which can have a different number of rows, or is it all together a new question?

Comment: @swepab Sure, it's possible. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838733/stratified-sampling-in-numpy) is a link with which to start. I can only continue this later, so drop here a note if you need something further (of course, you can always open a new question).

Answer (score 1):

This samples one random per id:

```
for id in sorted(set(df["id_1"])):
    print(df[df["id_1"] == id].sample(1))
```

PS:

translated above solution using pythons list comprehension, returning a list of of indices:

```
idx = [df[df["id_1"] == val].sample(1).index[0] for val in sorted(set(df["id_1"]))]
```